# Booting from hard drive fails after installing Centos from USB Stick

Tags: centos, installation, usb

I created a Centos Live 5.4 Bootable USB drive.  I used this to install Centos on a HP Netbook.

When the system goes to write the Grub boot loader to disk, it wants to write the boot loader to the usb drive (/dev/sda), not the hard disk (/dev/hda).  I do have the option of writing the boot loader to /dev/hda, (not to the mbr!)  but when I reboot I get an load error and the Grub prompt.

How can I get Centos booting from the hard disk instead of using the USB key.

Comment: Maybe by asking this question on the appropriate forum of superuser.com

Comment: @chopper3 - When did you score a diamond?

Comment: about 2 months or so ago, it was on the SO blog, there was a vote etc.

Comment: @Chopper3 - Ah, shows how much I pay attention. Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

If you used whole hard disk for centOS, it might be possible to fix your grub.

From shell prompt, try this command below

```
#grub-install --recheck /dev/hda
```

After that exit to reboot.

If grub-install does not work for you, you can try to fix it manually from grub prompt. From grub prompt

```
grub> root (hd0,0)
```

Assumed that you've installed your boot on your first partition. Otherwise replace the last '0' with appropriate number. After that

```
grub> setup (hd0)
```

Then exit and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the partitions on the hard disk first?  Last time I worked on a netbook, it had a hidden partition for system recovery.  You may need to wipe this out first.